# spring boot - mongodb - DBRef Hashset accepts duplicates

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot

I have a user entity with a set of favorite items. and i annotate the field as follows

```
class user {
    @Id 
    private String id;
    @DBREF
    private HashSet <Item> favorites;
    //empty and full constructor + getters and setters
}
```

when i want to add a new item to the set i get the user from the database, get his favorites insert new item and save user. for adding and removing items I use the add and remove functions of the Set interface.

the problem: the set accepts duplicates, and remove function does not remove from the set

**EDIT**: here is how I add an item to the set:

```
public void addItem(Strin username, String id){
    Item item= itemService.findById(id);
    User user = userService.findByUsername(username);
    HashSet<Item> set= user.getFavorites();
    set.add(Item);
    user.setFavorites(set);
    this.userRepository.save(user);
}
```

Comment: I'm not really following what the issue is, if your `id` is unique then that's all you need no?

Comment: Item here is an object and yes it has unique id but somehow duplicates get in and remove doesn't work. when I remove @DBRef and use HashSet<String> when direct id values it works. Obviously this is not the way to go in a nosql db. when i will need a user's favorite items i will reach to the db twice.

Comment: Im guessing eventhough the object in set and the one being added or removed have same ids, somehow, the one being added is considered new.

Comment: What query do you use to "add" a new item to the set ?

Comment: have you overridden `equals` and `hashCode` methods for `Item`. can you post the Item class?

Comment: To add a new item to the set, I first get the user by id from the repository, then get item by id and add it to the user then save the user

Comment: yes i did implement those nothing changed. I used item id in equals  and for hashCode, I use id and name of item

Answer (score 0):

For future reference, I had to correctly implement the equals function of class Item:

```
@Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {

        if (o == this) return true;
        if (!(o instanceof Item)) {
            return false;
        }
        Item item = (Item) o;

        // wrong (for comparing Strings): return id == item.getId()

        // right:
        return id.equals(item.getId());
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(id);
    }
```